# Get active_id in javascript Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

Hello I'm trying to pass my active_id from my res.partner to the JS.
But no luck.
I tried with dataset active_id but it's always undefined.
and i can't find any solution in the docs.
Here's my JS File:

```
odoo.define('melax_category.my_dialog_partner', function(require){"user strict";
  var core = require('web.core');
  var session = require('web.session');
  var qweb = core.qweb;
  var mixins = core.mixins;
//   var Widget = require('web.Widget');
  var Model = require('web.Model');
  var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
  var model_category = new Model('res.partner');
//   var dataset = this.dataset;
//   var active_id = dataset.ids[dataset.index];

function ActionBuildTreeBuyerPartner(parent, action){
    console.log(this.id)
    var dialog = new Dialog(document.body, {
                    title: "Categories Web Acheteur",
                    subtitle: '<input id="search-tree-buyer" type="text">',
                    size: 'big',
                    $content: '\
                               <div id="tree-buyer-container"></div>\
                               ',
                });

    TREE = $('#tree-buyer-container')
    dialog.open();
    DESTROY_TREE($('#tree-buyer-container'))
    BUILD_TREE_PARTNER_MODE(model_category, $('#tree-buyer-container'))

}

function ActionBuildTreeSellerPartner(parent, action){
    var dialog = new Dialog(document.body, {
                    title: "Categories Web Vendeur",
                    // subtitle: "Tree Builder Partner Sub Title!",
                    size: 'big',
                    $content: '<div id="tree-seller-container"></div>',
                });

    TREE = $('#tree-seller-container')
    dialog.open();
    // DESTROY_TREE($('#tree-seller-container'))
    // BUILD_TREE_PARTNER_MODE(model_category, $('#tree-buyer-container'))

}
    core.action_registry.add("build_tree_buyer_partner", ActionBuildTreeBuyerPartner);
    core.action_registry.add("build_tree_seller_partner", ActionBuildTreeSellerPartner);
});
```

and here's my python file where for example i'm trying to pass my active_id(self.id):

```
@api.multi
def build_tree_buyer_partner(self):
    _logger.error(self)
    # My active Id
    _logger.error(self.id)       
    return {
        'type':'ir.actions.client',
        'tag': 'build_tree_buyer_partner'
    }
```

Comment: Same problem here. When I try to get the active id of a record which has not been created yet, I always get undefined. I would like to pass the current record to Python to replicate the `self` of the `onchange` method.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you can get the current id by using:

```
var dataset = this.dataset;
var active_id = dataset.ids[dataset.index];
```

Python

```
@api.model 
def _get_active_id(self):
    return self._context.get('active_id')

deploy_config_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer', required=True, default=_get_active_id)
```